# Is memory logged in a transaction?

Tags: transactions, memory

Data in memory during a transaction is deleted when execution stops. This means this information is not stored in the contract state, but is the information that was in memory during the transaction still stored in the logs of the transaction?

Answer (score 3):

No, memory is never part of the blockchain, it only exist during the execution of a contract in the EVM.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I found this recently "And if you want the intermediate execution details of the transaction, use debug.traceTransaction(txHash). Note that this data is not available in --fast synced blockchain data:

Comment: Continued:      pc: 0,
      stack: [],
      storage: {}
  }, {
      depth: 1,
      error: "",
      gas: 1039656,
      gasCost: 3,
      memory: null,
      op: "PUSH1",
      pc: 2,
      stack: ["0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060"],
      storage: {}
  }, {
  ...
  }, {
      depth: 1,
      error: "",
      gas: 100000,
      gasCost: 0,
      memory: ["290decd9548b62a8d60345a988386fc84ba6bc95484008f6362f93160ef3e653", "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004", ..............."

Comment: Is that hash after "memory" the information that was in memory or the hash of the function that was called?

Comment: @Curious2424 Transactions have deterministic behavior if you execute a transaction again, then you will generate the same memory. Trace transaction does exactly that it executes the transaction and record all intemediate steps.  The content of the memory is not stored in the blockchain, but if you trace a transaction you will be able to examine the state of it in each step.